# How to properly use Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models

You've probably heard of the game League of Legends. Its ranked system is pretty simple -> if you win = you gain points, if you lose = you lose points. So the model:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf

overall_winrate = float(input("overall_winrate: "))/100
winrate_after_vic = float(input("winrate_after_vic: "))/100
winrate_after_def = float(input("winrate_after_def: "))/100



tfd = tfp.distributions
initial_distribution = tfd.Categorical(probs=[1-overall_winrate,overall_winrate]) #Overall winrate// right - win / left - loss
transition_distribution = tfd.Categorical(probs=[[1-winrate_after_def, winrate_after_def],
                                                 [1-winrate_after_vic, winrate_after_vic]])
observation_distribution = tfd.Normal(loc=[-24.923076, 23.545454], scale=[-4., 3.])


model = tfd.HiddenMarkovModel(
    initial_distribution=initial_distribution,
    transition_distribution=transition_distribution,
    observation_distribution=observation_distribution,
    num_steps=20)

mean = model.mean()

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  print(mean.numpy())
```

The point of this programme is to tell how many points will you have after a certain number of games. Overall winrate e.g 52%, winrate_after_vic = the winrate after a victory e.g 51%, winrate_after_def = the winrate after a defeat e.g 50% .

observation_distribution => loc = [how much points I lose after a defeat, how much points I win after a victory]  scale = [standard deviation of the losing points e.g [-20,-28], [standard deviation of the victory points e.g [20,27]]

So now, to the problem:
The output is the following code:

```
[0.32902718 0.5473299  0.55257034 0.5526953  0.55269814 0.55269814
 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814
 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814 0.55269814
 0.55269814 0.55269814]
```

I want to see an end result after 20 games. For example: after 20 games I have won overall 15 points. But the output is just a mid value of the losing and wining points, which I don't know how to make a use of.